# указатель на функцию в классе

Tags: c++, linux, windows

Понемножку перехожу с си на c++. У меня возникла такая проблема. Вот класс.

```
class Model {
  private:
    void draw_with_texture ( void );
    void draw_without_texture ( void );
    void (*map) ( void );
    void switch_to ( void );
  public:
    Sprite *texture;
};
```

Ну и где-то в коде проверяю.

```
void Model::switch_to ( ) {
        if ( this->texture ) this->map = draw_with_texture;
        else this->map = draw_without_texture;
}
```

Если бы я писал на си, то проблем бы не было, потому что не в классе производится операция.

```
./src/engine/model.cpp: In member function ‘void Model::switch_to()’:
./src/engine/model.cpp:12:35: error: cannot convert ‘Model::draw_with_texture’ from type ‘void (Model::)()’ to type ‘void (*)()’
  if ( this->texture ) this->map = draw_with_texture;
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./src/engine/model.cpp:13:19: error: cannot convert ‘Model::draw_without_texture’ from type ‘void (Model::)()’ to type ‘void (*)()’
  else this->map = draw_without_texture;
```

Можно ли решить мою проблему и как?

Comment: Я конечно решил эту задачу. Вынес функции за пределы класса и в функцию передаю класс. Блин, а если сделать friend функцию, но как? Так как я сделал за пределы класса, то приватные свойства стали недоступны.

Comment: О, friend помогло, теперь доступны приватные свойства.

Comment: Так вы решили свой вопрос? Тогда удалите его... А в вашем случае можно попробовать описать map как `void (*Model::*map) ( void );` и присвоение типа `this->map = &Model::draw_without_texture;`

Comment: При определении функции_члена  this указатель неявно присутствует. Для чего вы его делаете явным для одного метода, а для другого нет?  Это не является ошибкой, но все же...  Когда это не является необходимым, лучше не использовать this дабы не навредить читаемость или ввести читателью в заблуждение, что есть еще и  внешные сущности с таким названием.

Comment: @Harry теперь он ругается на это` ./src/engine/model.cpp:23:14: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘((Model*)this)->Model::map (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* ((Model*)this)->Model::map) (...)’
  this->map ( );`

Comment: Да ну почитайте хоть немного учебник!

Answer (score 2):

Указатель на ваши функции в классе должен иметь тип `void (Model::*)()`, а вы его объявили с типом `void (*)()`. Это совершенно разные, никак не совместимые типы.

Правильно

```
void (Model::*map) ( void );
```

(если уж вам нравится писать `void` в скобках).

Ну и, разумеется, при вызове надо учитывать, что вызов производится не через указатель на свободную функцию, а через *указатель на метод класса*.

Comment: Дополню ответ, для тех кто не в курсе разницы между функцией и методом. Метод - это специальный тип функции, которая кроме явного списка параметров принимает еще один неявный - `this`, с типом указатель на объект/экземпляр класса, для которого объявлен метод. Чтобы не путать этакие похожие указатели в C++ был введен специальный синтаксис, указанный в ответе и сообщении об ошибке.

Comment: У меня не работает такой способ. Немогу вызвать this->map